# Combine output of multiple ImageDataGenerators to one tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Let's say I want to apply two different `preprocessing_functions` in two`ImageDataGenerator`s to an Image and then concatenate those outputs to a one tensor to train the model.

i.e., If I have RGB images, my model would expect six channels in the input tensor because I want to concatenate the output of two generators (each will have 3 channels).

Concretely:

```
# first preproc function
def preproc_function_1(image):
    image = np.array(image)
    return image * 0.1

# second preproc function
def preproc_function_2(image):
    image = np.array(image)
    return image * 0.2

# datagen_1 - that applies preproc_function_1 
train_datagen_1 = ImageDataGenerator(
     preprocessing_function=preproc_function_1)

# datagen_2 - that applies preproc_function_2
train_datagen_2 = ImageDataGenerator(
     preprocessing_function=preproc_function_2)
```

If we have such parallel `ImageDataGenerator`s I assume, we want to use two validation generators as well

```
 validation_datagen_1 = ImageDataGenerator()

 validation_datagen_2 = ImageDataGenerator()
```

*Question:*

How can I proceed to use `model.fit_generator()`?

I think I have to use `<generator>.flow_from_directory()` (my data can be read from `flow_from_directory`) to supply `generator` in   [`model.fit_generator()`](https://keras.io/models/model/#fit_generator) to train the model.

Do I need to create two `<generator>.flow_from_directory()` objects? I'm lost here.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

It's easier if you just create a single preprocessing function:

```
def preproc(image):
     return np.concatenate([
                            preproc_function_1(image), 
                            preproc_function_2(image)
                           ], axis=-1) #or axis=1 if channels_first
```

### Option 2 - Using two generators

Since you have the 6 channel problem, this custom generator should work. But you will not have 'preprocessing', you will have 'postprocessing' instead:

```
class Processor(keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, keras_generator)
        self.keras_generator = keras_generator

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.keras_generator(

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        batch_x, batch_y = self.keras_generator[i]

        #do batch processing here

        return processed_batch_x, batch_y

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        self.keras_generator.on_epoch_end()

custom_generator = Processor(validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(...))
```

Comment: Hi @Daniel Möller thank you for the answer!. I have created a one `train_datagen` and a one `valid_datagen`  `ImageDataGenerator` objects using a combined preprocessing function. But I can't figure out how to use `train_datagen.flow_from_directory()` and `model.fit_generator()` from then onward. When `model.fit_generator()` is called, I'm getting this error: `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (150,150,6) into shape (150,150,3)`. I think the reason for this is the use of [`train_datagen.flow_from_directory()`](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#flow_from_directory) TBC..

Comment: Per docs, the output of `flow_from_directory()` method is a `DirectoryIterator yielding tuples of (x, y) where x is a numpy array containing a batch of images with shape (batch_size, *target_size, channels) `. How can I specify the target depth to be 6? My images in the directory are RGB so I think this defaults to 3. When debugging, I can see that the error is returned in [this line](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/095aea9a029d52af618f3b1e8a4f93ef83f51d91/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py#L240) where `batch_x.shape`=32,150,150,3 and `x.shape` =150,150,6

Comment: Any idea how can I proceed from here on?

Comment: And, it seems like there's an issue here on this: [Using ImageDataGenerator for images with more than 3 channels](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4664)

Comment: It's because your `model` is expecting 3 channels. `input_shape`

Comment: I've forgotten to mention this. No, my model is correctly built to accept inputs of depth 6.

Comment: Ok, there is a workaround in the answer, but it will not be "preprocessing" anymore, it will be "postprocessing" the selected images.